# How to handle number too big on input in C?

Tags: c

my task is to make a sum of digits of a given number (without knowing its size). All I know is that the number is natural positive (including 0), so 0,1,2,3,4....10^x. The number will be given on stdin, so probably scanf is a solution. I know how I would do the sum, but I dont know how to store (some people suggested not to store) this number because even long long might not be enough if the number is too big.
Please answer more accurate, I'm C beginner. Thanks

Comment: Read the input as a series of digits rather than a single number.

Comment: How do I achieve that? Like can I split scanf or something? Because whenever I enter input to scanf (number 10^100), it will store to given variable in scanf.

Comment: You can store it as a string. and then do the calculations in decimal.

Comment: try using `getchar()`

Comment: If you are a beginner, put scanf on the shelf.  Do not use it at all until you know the language well enough to understand its limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input number can be arbitrarily large, it is indeed better not to try and convert it as a number but to operate on the digits typed. Note that this method always works anyway:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long sum = 0;
    int has_number = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int c = getchar();  // read the next byte from input
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            sum += c - '0'; // add the digit value
            has_number = 1;
        } else {
            if (has_number) {
                printf("sum=%ld\n", sum);  // output the current sum and
                has_number = 0;
                sum = 0;                  // reset the sum to zero
            }
            if (c == EOF)
                break;      // stop at end of file
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program can handle very large numbers, up to at least 200 million digits.

Comment: Yep, this works, but since the number is given from the keyboard, the condition would be 

**if (c == '\n') break;**

Comment: @MartinCigarsky The source of  the input has no bearing on the logic.  If the user entering data at the tty doesn't know how to close the stream, then you have a user education problem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell [user education problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847347/how-to-handle-number-too-big-on-input-in-c#comment107654750_60847520) --> 

Comment: I amended the code to allow for more than one number to be typed, separated by any non digit character sequence. Just testing with `if (c == '\n')` would require the user to press enter after the number, which is not necessary if the end-of-file can be signalled some other way (such as Ctrl-D on unix terminals).